# Z-index position of overlapping elements with opacity

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a scenario where I need to "activate" a selection of text and "bring it forward", by setting opacity to 1 from a default of 0.5. I can't bring an element forward though by setting a higher z-index. I've tried playing with `position: relative` but no success. See the snippet, by setting a higher z-index to `.c1`, `.c2` is still visible. Any ideas?

```css
mark {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.c1 {
  background: rgb(255,236,132);
  z-index: 1;
}

.c2 {
  background: rgb(254,183,183, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <mark class="c1">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <mark class="c2">laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis</mark> aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat</mark> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

By setting a z-index to the first element, it still remains in the back of the second element.

Comment: position:relative and z-index:-1 to c2 (remove  z-index from c1)

Comment: @TemaniAfif that solution makes the text disappear as well.

Comment: which is logical since you want c2 under c1 and the color of c1 is opaque

Comment: @TemaniAfif the content of c2 is also part of c1 though. How can I preserve it? That is what I mean by "bring it forward" in my question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I also have a click handler on both (to "activate" or "bring forward"). z-index: -1 on c2 makes it unclickable even if it's partly outside of c1 and not completely overlapped

Comment: edit your question to add more details and if possible show us a screenshot of the result you want because actually it's not clear what you want.